# Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, Windows 10 and IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I have been having a hard time getting Visual Studio 2015 CE and IIS express to run on my windows 10 machine. Even when I make a default MVC5 web application and attempt to run it without making any changes I usually see the error below.

> Configuration Error
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Business, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)

I have read a few posts that talk about using the `netstat -ano` command and finding the PID of the process using the same port, it always ends up being PID 4 aka "SYSTEM". I have tried uninstalling IIS Express and enabling the local IIS under "Windows Features" and what happens is I receive the same error, but after like 10 page refreshes the site loads.

Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: Your attempt is in vain. Should use handles utility from SysInternals suite to see which process is using the Business.dll and kill that process.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a Band-Aid at best? As was mentioned when using local IIS my work around is refreshing the page continuously, I am wondering if maybe something was installed improperly.

Comment: Try uninstalling IIS Express 10, then download and install IIS Express 8. Had a lot of trouble with the new one. After going back to 8 it works like a charm again

Comment: I'll give it a shot, and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say it, but the way I resolved this issue was by reverting back to Visual Studio 2013, I can't state for certain the the issue was with the 2015 Community Edition of Visual Studio, but at this time VS2013 is what works.